# How to generate random Base36 IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, uniqueidentifier

Is there a way of generating **random** [base36 identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) with a defined character count in SQL Server?

I have searched and found many examples of converting base 36 to int and vice versa, but not for randomly generating unique IDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution a bit verbose but works and can easily be adapted to a variety of requirements. Here's some sample output:

```
aapx0k  k4fdbb  vzbl5x
8vr1bs  gbix1q  g5kctv
he6e50  m9j0m0  2vz53l
yw72hs  hgbo5h  3oen9v
6t4q75  337670  5sf3h4
yqr35s  xoh4hh  tc0wtf
w7trkj  lnnpdk  zk2ln1
1gt7qr  l6m72n  ja5kvm
kg6f9y  6t3b7a  ujfr0i
2jatgo  0yv8rv  wvbjfa
```

Note that you need to create a view to wrap the use of RAND which is not allowed inside a UDF. So this solution needs two db objects, a view and a udf.

```
CREATE VIEW ViewRandInt AS (SELECT RAND() * 36 as RandInt)
GO

CREATE FUNCTION GetRandomBase36Id
(
    @charCount AS INT
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @characters CHAR(36),
            @result VARCHAR(MAX),
            @counter INT,
            @randNum INT

    SELECT @characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
           @result = '',
           @counter = 0;


    WHILE @counter < @charCount
    BEGIN
        SELECT @randNum = RandInt FROM ViewRandInt
        SET @result = @result + SUBSTRING(@characters, @randNum+1, 1)
        SET @counter = @counter + 1
    END

    RETURN @result;

END

-- Test:
SELECT dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6), dbo.GetRandomBase36Id(6)
```

Comment: @Kumar: I think you may have accepted the answer before I posted a fix to a bug in the original answer. Please get the latest code sample. (The original code was off by one character and when `z` was the random character selected the final ID did not include it.)

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL** version of Paul Sasik's answer:

*Notice the important change in the view and : `FLOOR(RandInt * 36) INTO v_randNum`*

```
CREATE VIEW `ViewRandInt` AS (select rand() AS `RandInt`);

DROP function IF EXISTS `GetRandomBase36Id`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetRandomBase36Id`(
    p_charCount INT
) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_characters CHAR(36);
    DECLARE v_result LONGTEXT;
    DECLARE v_counter INT;
    DECLARE v_randNum INT;

    SET v_characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
           v_result = '',
           v_counter = 0;
           
    WHILE v_counter < p_charCount
    DO
        SELECT FLOOR(RandInt * 36) INTO v_randNum FROM ViewRandInt;
        SET v_result = Concat(v_result , SUBSTRING(v_characters, v_randNum +1, 1));
        SET v_counter = v_counter + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN v_result;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

-- Test
SELECT GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, GetRandomBase36Id(6)
, GetRandomBase36Id(6);
```