# Efficiency of comparing IDs as short strings

Tags: .net, database

I was looking for a solution of generating readable, short, unique strings in order to store files in database. (file's ID = generated string). I have found this answer [Generating human-readable/usable, short but unique IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543715/generating-human-readable-usable-short-but-unique-ids). According to the answer: ***you will have to store the created IDs and check for duplicates on creation to ensure uniqueness.*** The question is: is it efficient to compare such strings each time the ID creation is done? Does it mean we have to compare every single row to check whether a duplicate exists?

Comment: This is what unique indexes are good at; the data's already sorted so checking for duplicates can be an efficient operation.

Comment: Okay, so let's say it's efficient when it comes to database storage, but I want to include Entity Framework here also. Does following query in EF: "from c in context.Files where c.FileId == id select c;" will fetch and map to object only these rows with given id or all rows?